# TestCase Laravel Custom Command returns empty response

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my custom command, but when I run it does not return anything. I do not know if it's a problem with my assertion. I'm using Laravel 5.6

```
class CommandsTest extends TestCase
{
    //Command morty:bloquear_usuarios_demitidos
    public function test_if_can_run_command_morty_bloquear_usuarios_demitidos()
    {

        $response = $this->artisan('morty:bloquear_usuarios_demitidos');

        $response->assertContains('Executado');
    }
}
```

[phpunit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76eJU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are expecting an artisan command to 'return'. They don't 'return' things, they just get executed. There could be an exit code, but that is it.

If you stop and look at the method you are calling `artisan` it returns an `int`. You can't expect anything other than an `int` which would be the exit code.

[Laravel 5.6 API - `InteractsWithConsole@artisan`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithConsole.html#method_artisan)

Comment: *There could be an exit code, but that is it.*, **There is an exit code**. I think OP wants to assert `$this->line('Executado')`.